# Migrated web service to .NET Core 2.0 and returning json

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, servicestack

I have migrated my web service to .NET Core 2.0, it works fine but I have problem with getting response as json string.

Method on api:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), 200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(EntityNotFoundErrorResult), 404)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCurrenciesAsync()
    {
        var result = await service.GetByTypeAsync(ObjectType.Currency.ToString());

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

that is returning proper json as `result`:

```
"{\"elements\": [{\"Id\": \"1\", \"Symbol\": \"PLN\"},{\"Id\": \"2\", \"Symbol\": \"SIT\"}]}"
```

Then on client I'm using [service stack](https://servicestack.net/) to get my currencies as string:

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<CurrencyData> GetCurrencies()
    {
        string response = null;

        try
        {
            response = api.Get<string>("/Currencies");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(response) ? null :  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TempCurrencyClass>(response).elements;
    }
```

And the `response` looks like this:

```
"\"{\\\"elements\\\": [{\\\"Id\\\": \\\"1\\\", \\\"Symbol\\\": \\\"PLN\\\"},{\\\"Id\\\": \\\"2\\\", \\\"Symbol\\\": \\\"SIT\\\"}]}\""
```

So `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` throws deserialization exception:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
```

But it works when I'm deserializing response to sting and to objest then:

```
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(response);
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TempCurrencyClass>(x).elements;
```

I'm guessing that the problem is on client right? Well strange thing is that it works just fine on .NET Core 1.1

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it appears that in .NET Core 2.0 `[Produces("application/json")]` has changed and it is serializing string outputs to json so I had it serialized twice... solution for this os to replace `[Produces("application/json")]` with     `[Produces("text/plain")]` ovet the method / controller

Answer (score 0):

In my case, request was having header **Accepts : application/json**

Removing this header has stopped sending json with escape characters. application/json response is default for .NET Core.