# Web-API Sends Escaped Strings

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am tinkering around with .NET Core 2.1.4 and a Web-API project.

My code contains some hardcoded dummy data, in form of normal or verbatim string literals. Anyway, the result looks the same, no matter what kind of literal I used.

```
string status1 = "{\"ID\":\"7A\",\"status\":\"available\"}";
string status2 = @"{""ID"":""7A"",""status"":""available""}";
```

I return them by calling the `Ok` function:

```
IActrionResult result = Ok(status1);
```

I used the same test project some months ago with .NET Core 1.1 and everything worked fine. The returned result look like in the following snippet and fitted my needs for responding with a valid JSON string for demonstration purposes.

```
{"ID":"7A","status":"available"}
```

After upgrading to dotnet core 2, the server returns the same string, but with additional double quotes and escape characters, as you can see below.

```
"{\"ID\":\"7A\",\"status\":\"available\"}"
```

This seems to be related to [Web API returns escaped JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309658/web-api-returns-escaped-json)

I would like to understand why this is happening and what mechanism is controlling this.

Comment: Can you add the code for the `Ok` method?

Comment: @Hackerman This is part of the .NET code (ControllerBase.cs).

Comment: return response by defining its media-type might solve your issue, like this : `var resp = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent(status1, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") };` `return resp;`

Comment: Are the browser same for your 2 tests with .Net Core 1.1 and .Net Core 2.0? A typical browser may request specific format of data.

Comment: @RahulHendawe: Sorry, but this is not the point. Had the definitions already in my project.

Comment: @AfsharMohebbi: The behaviour is the same in Edge, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrated web service to .NET Core 2.0 and returning json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46785619/migrated-web-service-to-net-core-2-0-and-returning-json)